# PHPUnit class not found in test

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpunit

I have an existing PHP project. I need to test a class MyClass. I created a test under the same package. 
When running with IntelliJ 2016.1 I get error Fatal error: Class 'MyClass' not found in

This is example of the test

```
<?php
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

In Run Configuration I entered Custom working directory as the Composer `vendor` package.
PHPUnit is loaded from the `include path`

Under Settings->PHP I added the phpunit Composer package and my class package to the include path.

Under Settings->PHP->PHPUnit default config file and default bootstrap are unchecked.

What else should I configure so I can run MyClassTest without errors and test the class MyClass?

Comment: I haven't worked with intellij-idea configuration. But try to add a backslash before the `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and see if it works.

Comment: Backslash didn't help `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class is part of a composer package, or you use the composer autoloader for your project files, you can set up `vendor/autoload.php` as bootstrap file.

If you have set up a custom autoloader for project classes, you need to create your own boostrap.php file for PHPUnit and register the autoloader there.

Comment: There is a `vendor/autoload.php` file. But in Settings->PHP->PHPUnit it's set to 'Load from include path'. What else should I configure in the `vendor/autoload.php`? Because if I set only as custom autoloader it doesn't help.

Comment: Don't change this file, it is generated by composer. "Load from include path" only refers to PHPUnit itself, not your project files, you don't want to change that. Choose `vendor/autoload.php` as "Default bootstrap file".

Comment: I chose `vendor/autoload.php` as default bootstrap file. But the error is still there. Perhaps I should look at other settings?

Comment: As I wrote above, it depends on how you autoload the files of your project normally.